# How to run code at exiting point of web request in java

Tags: java, filtering

I have a web application written in java. i would like to run a 'clean up' method that would run at the end of each web request as in after all the work has been done. I'm looking for something like a filter just that it would run at the end of the request and not at the beginning.

What's the way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ServletRequestListener interface:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html

Comment: I was going to suggest doing the clean up after calling `chain.doFilter()` in a custom filter, but this looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks stoupa.
Details can be found here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28959/listener.htm#BABBHEGC

basically you write a class that implements ServletRequestListener, and then add some configuration in your web.xml

```
 <listener> 
      <listener-class>SessionLifeCycleEventExample</listener-class> 
   </listener>
```